# How to handle errors for functions returning a value

Tags: swift, function, error-handling

I have a function that checks if a Core data record exists before creating the record, and returns a boolean: true if it exists, false if it doesn't. Inside is nested a try, catch statement. How can I properly handle the error in a scenario like this where there is a return statement? Currently, I have the check implementation but if the catch is activated, there is nothing to return. I can return true to stop the record being made, but this isn't 'true'

```
func checkIfExists(id: String) -> Bool{
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Conversions> = Conversions.fetchRequest()
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id == %@", id)
    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
    fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 1

    do {
        let count = try PersistenceService.context.count(for: fetchRequest)
        if (count == 0){
            return false
        } else {
            return true
        }
    }
    catch let error  {
        print("Could not fetch \(error)")
        return true // missing return in function
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think your `checkIfExists` method cannot handle the error elegantly. This is a good sign that the error should be propagated to the caller and handled there instead:

```
func checkIfExists(id: String) throws -> Bool{
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Conversions> = Conversions.fetchRequest()
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id == %@", id)
    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
    fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 1
    let count = try PersistenceService.context.count(for: fetchRequest)
    return count != 0
}
```

In the caller, you can `do...catch` the error, and hopefully (if the caller needs to return a value), *can* return a meaningful value even if an error occurs.

If the caller still can't return a meaningful value, you propagate the error up again, and eventually you'll reach one that handles user input or something (which doesn't return a value). There, you will show an error message to the user.

---

Depending on your design, returning `false` when an error occurs could also be an option - if an error occurs while accessing the DB file, just assume it doesn't exist.